# Git Bash commands are blocked by ransomware protection

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, controlled-folder-access

I've discovered that Git Bash commands are being blocked by Windows 10 Ransomware protection. This happens only if I am trying to execute them in Windows folders such as Documents. I've tested this with `mkdir` and `touch` but it probably involves more commands.

The error I am getting looks like this:

```
DESKTOP-FBRH45G MINGW64 ~/Documents/Git_Projects
$ mkdir example_folder
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘example_folder’: No such file or directory
```

This occurs when the protection of controlled folder access is turned on.

[image]

When the protection is turned off, the command is executed:

```
DESKTOP-FBRH45G MINGW64 ~/Documents/Git_Projects
$ mkdir example_folder

DESKTOP-FBRH45G MINGW64 ~/Documents/Git_Projects
$ ls
example_folder/
```

It doesn't make any difference if I run Git Bash with administrative rights. I've tried adding Git to allowed application settings but it does not make any difference either:

[image]

The only workaround is currently to disable the protection or move Git projects to another folder; however, I would like to know if there's anything I can do to make these commands work in my Documents folders as this is where I wanted to store the projects.

The current version of my git is:

```
DESKTOP-FBRH45G MINGW64 ~
$ git --version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Git functioning with ransomware protection, you need to literally exclude every .exe file in the Git directory where it is installed. You must also exclude mingw64\bin\git.exe.